# insert record into database with angular,php and mysql error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a controller that gets me from records from a table in a database which i bind it over to some textfields which will then be inserted into a different table. When i submitt i get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'resp_fname' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.addnew
```

JS

```
.controller('profile_detail_ctrl',['$scope','$http',,function($scope,$http){

   $http.get('http://localhost/proj//templates/profile/content.php).success(function(data){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        $scope.content=data;

        $scope.addnew=function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $http.post("http://localhost/proj/scripts/insert.php",
        {'resp_name':$scope.item.resp_fname,'fpage':$scope.item.resp_fpage,'resp_id':$scope.item.resp_id})
        .success(function(data){
        console.log(data)
        });
        }   
       });
}])
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="project" ng-repeat="item in content">
<input type="text" ng-model="item.resp_fname"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="item.resp_fpage"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="item.resp_id"/>
<button  class="button button-positive" ng-click="addnew();">Insert </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are in a repeater so the item is not an attribute of the scope, so you get `undefined`. You have also some quotes problem in the code.

You should pass the item to the function and the event if you want to prevent the default, but in your case you are not in a form.

**JS**

```
.controller('profile_detail_ctrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){

   $http.get('http://localhost/proj//templates/profile/content.php').success(function(data){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        $scope.content=data;
   });
   $scope.addnew=function(event,item) {
       event.preventDefault();
            $http.post("http://localhost/proj/scripts/insert.php",
                {'resp_name':item.resp_fname,'fpage':item.resp_fpage,'resp_id':item.resp_id})
            .success(function(data){
                console.log(data)
            });
        };
}])
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="profile_detail_ctrl" ng-repeat="item in content">
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.resp_fname"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.resp_fpage"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.resp_id"/>
    <button  class="button button-positive" ng-click="addnew($event,item);">Insert</button>
</div>
```